# Split a table into another table with x rows in each group

Tags: python, sqlite

Time and sale data from tastytrade.com I'm trying to turn into candle data with 1000 ticks per candle. I am OK using dataframe, Pandas, NumPy, SQLite and Python.

For SQLite how to select records divided into groups of 1,000 records each? I tried turning the table into a dataframe, then converting into string to loop through the slices of the string, but that couldn't apply max or min to the parts of the dataframe. I'm getting 7 groups of 70,000 and they only have one column which says "false."

```
from decimal import Decimal
from tastytrade.account import Account
from tastytrade.instruments import Equity
from tastytrade.instruments import Future
from tastytrade.order import NewOrder, OrderAction, OrderTimeInForce, OrderType, PriceEffect
import time
import Test_file
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import requests
import sqlite3
import fut
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np
import torch


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///iterist.db', echo=False)
con = sqlite3.connect("iterist.db")
cur=con.cursor()

dinper = ['3']
n=['/ESU3']

a="""select symbol, high, time, volume
from tasty_candles limit 70000
"""
df = pd.read_sql(a, engine)
df = df[df['symbol']==symbols]
df['rows']=df.index
h=df['rows'].astype(str)
n=h.values.tolist()
sym_list = n[0:3000] # take a slice of the symbols from earlier
chunk_size = 2999 #
num_calls = int(len(n) / chunk_size) + 1
df_hold_list = [] #collect intermidiary calls
for i in range(0,num_calls):
    sym_string = ','.join(n[chunk_size*i:chunk_size*(i+1)])
    qf=sym_string.split()
    gt=type(qf)
    con1 = (df['rows'].isin(qf))
    df_hold_list.append(df)
dff = pd.concat(df_hold_list)
dff.to_sql(name='fut_candles', con=engine, if_exists='replace')
```

Answer (score 0):

This converts time and sale data into tick sized candle chunks. More database work will need to be done to find the max, min, open, and close of each candle. You can use SQL or dataframe, depending on your strategy.

```
from decimal import Decimal
from tastytrade.account import Account
from tastytrade.instruments import Equity
from tastytrade.instruments import Future
from tastytrade.order import NewOrder, OrderAction,
OrderTimeInForce, OrderType, PriceEffect
import time
import Test_file
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import requests
import sqlite3
import fut
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np
import torch


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///iterist.db', echo=False)
con = sqlite3.connect("iterist.db")
cur=con.cursor()
cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS etimes')
cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS qtimes')
cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ytimes')
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE etimes (
    "index" BIGINT,
    "symbol" text,
    "start" text,
    "end" text);''')

fut_symbols=['/ESU3']

a="""select symbol, high, time, volume
from tasty_candles limit 70000
"""
df = pd.read_sql(a, engine)
df = df[df['symbol']=='/ESU3']
#df['rows']=df.index
std=df['time'].astype(str)
#print(std)
n=std.values.tolist()
sym_list = n[0:1000] # take a slice of the symbols from
                     earlier
chunk_size = 999 #
num_calls = int(len(n) / chunk_size) + 1
df_hold_list = [] #collect intermidiary calls
for i in range(0,num_calls):
    sym_string = ','.join(n[chunk_size*i:chunk_size*(i+1)])
    qf=sym_string.split(',')
    rt = pd.DataFrame(qf, columns= ['time'])
    start = (rt['time'].min(axis=0))
    end = (rt['time'].max(axis=0))
    etimes = pd.DataFrame({'start': [start], 'end': [end],
     'symbol': fut_symbols})
    print(etimes)
    etimes.to_sql(name='etimes', con=engine,
    if_exists='append')
ticks='''select high from tasty_candles
inner join etimes
where tasty_candles.time between etimes.start and
 etimes.end'''
candle=pd.read_sql(ticks, con=engine)
print(candle)
```